# Nginx rewrite rule - appending language prefix

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a site `spanish.com`. I want users to load pages under "es" directory, i.e., `spanish.com/es`. 
For example:

Users should see:
`spanish.com` but `spanish.com/es` is loaded

Users see `spanish.com/samplepage` but `spanish.com/es/samplepage` is loaded

---

I tried

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.spanish.com;
    return 301 $scheme://spanish.com$request_uri;
} 

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name spanish.com;
    limit_conn arbeit 32;

    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://$host/es/$1 permanent;

    ## Access and error logs.
    access_log /var/log/nginx/spanish.com_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/spanish.com_error.log;

    ...
}
```

but it results to infinite redirects to `http://spanish.com/es/es/es/es/es/es/es/...`

---

UPDATE
also, how do you exclude files from the rewrite rule? Like in apache?

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got through it:

```
## for the homepage
location = / {
    rewrite ^ /es;
}

## for the rest of the pages, excluding locations beginning
## with /<2char-lang-prefix>/*
## also excludes locations having only 3 characters, e.g. "/nb"
location ~* "^/(?!.{2,2}/).{3}.*$" {
    rewrite "^/(.*)$" /es/$1;
}
```